# wpf DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate how to enable/disable checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid, datatrigger

I have a `DataGrid` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` defined like this:

```html
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
          <CheckBox ToolTip="Select all items" 
            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Name="chkSelectAll" Checked="AllItem_Checked"
            Unchecked="UnCheckAll_UnChecked" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                                        
        <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Checked="Item_Checked" Unchecked="Item_UnChecked"
                IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" />                                        
       </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The grid has a binding with a list of objects.

I want, that for each object in `ItemsSource`, that the checkbox is readonly if the `IsSelected` attribute is true.

I don't know how to code this; I tried Binding IsHitTestVisible property to IsSelected ItemsSource Objects attribute but it's not working.

I googled about and found some topics about Multidatatriggers but can't understand how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that disables the `CheckBox` if `IsSelected` returns `true`:

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Checked="Item_Checked" Unchecked="Item_UnChecked" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I want now to permforme the same thing with datagrid Header binding checkBox (check all): if ALL Items in datagrid model (list<Item>) has IsSelected attribut set to TRUE then set Header CheckBox IsEnable property to False. How to do this ?